# How to properly write elements of a sample in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the elements of a sample in an SQL query. But I couldn't work this out. Here is the sample and outputs.

```
print(rnd_number)
[2, 8, 6, 4]

print("SELECT ingilizce FROM Sozluk WHERE Id IN ( '" + "'".join(str(rnd_number)).strip("[, ']") + "')")
SELECT ingilizce FROM Sozluk WHERE Id IN ( '2',' '8',' '6',' '4')
```

There is an additional apostroph between the elements. How can I solve this?

Comment: `'(' + ', '.join([2, 8, 6, 4]) + ')'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
print(
    "SELECT ingilizce FROM Sozluk WHERE Id IN (%s)"
    % ', '.join("'%s'" % i for i in rnd_number)
)
```

Output:

```
SELECT ingilizce FROM Sozluk WHERE Id IN ('2', '8', '6', '4')
```